# Как сделать такое отображение товаров на WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Пробовал с плагином WooCommerce , не получилось. Есть какой другой плагин в вордпресс, чтобы товары так отоброжались?

[image]

Comment: отображалось - проверочное слово "образ"

Comment: можно сделать такую страницу каталога ?:

Comment: Сделать в WooCommerce можно любое отображение, но вопрос слишком широк, чтобы получить здесь ответ. Наймите фрилансера.

Comment: примерно за сколько делают такие задачи?

Comment: Для WC есть готовые плагины для подобного

Comment: например какие?